# SQL i want to select time from timetable but checks all the time values in other table which not be selected

Tags: php, html, sql, web, time

here is the time table that I use

```
time "table"
---------------
1   |  07:00:00
2   |  08:00:00
3   |  09:00:00
4   |  10:00:00
5   |  11:00:00
6   |  12:00:00
7   |  13:00:00
8   |  14:00:00
```

these table is the one where I check the time must not be be select

```
sched_daytime "table"
---------------
Day          Start_time   End_time
-------------------------------------
Monday    |  07:00:00  | 08:00:00
Wednesday |  08:00:00  | 10:00:00
Monday    |  09:00:00  | 11:00:00
```

here is my sql query

```
select time.* 
from time,sched_daytime 
where time not between sched_daytime.s_time and sched_daytime.e_time 
AND sched_daytime.day = 'Monday' 
group by time.time
```

but the result is its still shows all time values in time table which suppose 
between 7:00 to 8:00 and 9:00 to 11:00:00 are not available time

its select all the values in time table please help sorry im still noob

Comment: What RDBMS you are using ???

Comment: duplicate of the question you asked a few hours ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100531/sql-time-query-how-can-i-select-in-a-time-table)

Comment: wampserver mysql localhost ... im noob sorry please help me

Comment: yes its a duplicate but more accurate question right ??? im sorry sir

Comment: what is the referencing column between these tables how do define the relation between these two columns ????

Comment: dont create a new account, do edit the original question

Comment: i think there is no rel. between 2 tables because I only want to check the used time in the sched_daytime table which time table query results must be 12:00:00 , 13:00:00 , 14:00:00

Answer (score 0):

try this:
select time 
from time,sched_daytime 
where day = 'Monday' 
AND time not between start_time and end_time 
group by time